# Link fails when building gRPC client for LND in C++

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, grpc

I'm trying to build a gRPC client for LND in C++, starting with the `WalletBalance` function. I've never used gRPC before, and I use `make` instead of `cmake`, but according to the documentation this is supposed to be possible. I am using the `pkg-config` files that get installed with gRPC, but they are not working.

Here is what I've successfully been able to do so far.

1. Build gRPC
2. Compile [lightning.proto](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/d44823f6e8580d2fa5f193a5382be351610f7c2b/lnrpc/lightning.proto)
3. Compile `lightning.pb.cc` and `lightning.grpc.pb.cc`
4. Link with `lightning.pb.cc.o` (but not `lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o`)

This is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>

#include "lightning.grpc.pb.h"
#include "lightning.pb.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace lnrpc;

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::Status;

class LightningClient
{
private:
    unique_ptr<Lightning::Stub> stub_;

public:
    LightningClient (shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> channel) : stub_ (Lightning::NewStub (channel)) {}

    unsigned long WalletBalance (const string& user)
    {
        WalletBalanceRequest request;
        WalletBalanceResponse reply;
        ClientContext context;

        Status status = stub_->WalletBalance (&context, request, &reply);

        if (status.ok ())
            return reply.total_balance ();
        else
            cout << status.error_code () << ": " << status.error_message () << endl;

        return 0;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> channel;// = CreateChannel ("localhost:10009", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials ());
    return 0;
}
```

This is my makefile:

```
lnd-grpc-client : lnd-grpc-client.o lightning.pb.cc.o lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o
    g++-10 -pthread -o lnd-grpc-client lnd-grpc-client.o lightning.pb.cc.o `pkg-config --libs --static protobuf`

lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o : lightning.grpc.pb.cc
    g++-10 -std=c++20 `pkg-config protobuf --cflags` -c -o lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o lightning.grpc.pb.cc

lightning.pb.cc.o : lightning.pb.cc
    g++-10 -std=c++20 `pkg-config protobuf --cflags` -c -o lightning.pb.cc.o lightning.pb.cc

lnd-grpc-client.o : lnd-grpc-client.cpp
    g++-10 -std=c++20 `pkg-config protobuf --cflags` -c -o lnd-grpc-client.o lnd-grpc-client.cpp
```

All of that compiles and links just fine. But I have the `CreateChannel` function commented out in my cpp file and I am not linking with `lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o`, both of which would be required if I am to get this working.

If I uncomment the CreateChannel function, it gives me a linker error saying `undefined reference to 'grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()'`. But there does not seem to be any pkg-config that solves that problem.

If I try to link with `lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o`, I get hundreds of linker errors. I can't post all of them, but here are a few:

```
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc5SliceD2Ev[_ZN4grpc5SliceD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to 'grpc_slice_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o: in function 'grpc::Slice::Slice(unsigned long)':
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc5SliceC2Em[_ZN4grpc5SliceC5Em]+0x32): undefined reference to 'grpc_slice_malloc'
/usr/bin/ld: lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o: in function 'grpc::SliceReferencingString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc22SliceReferencingStringERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN4grpc22SliceReferencingStringERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x50): undefined reference to 'grpc_slice_from_static_buffer'
/usr/bin/ld: lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o: in function 'grpc::ByteBuffer::ByteBuffer(grpc::Slice const*, unsigned long)':
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc10ByteBufferC2EPKNS_5SliceEm[_ZN4grpc10ByteBufferC5EPKNS_5SliceEm]+0x27): undefined reference to 'grpc_raw_byte_buffer_create'
/usr/bin/ld: lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o: in function 'grpc::ByteBuffer::~ByteBuffer()':
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc10ByteBufferD2Ev[_ZN4grpc10ByteBufferD5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to 'grpc_byte_buffer_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: lightning.grpc.pb.cc.o: in function 'grpc::ByteBuffer::Clear()':
lightning.grpc.pb.cc:(.text._ZN4grpc10ByteBuffer5ClearEv[_ZN4grpc10ByteBuffer5ClearEv]+0x27): undefined reference to 'grpc_byte_buffer_destroy'
```

I tried adding the `grpc` and `grpc++` pkg-config files to my makefile's link command, but that did not solve the problem.

Has anyone actually built a gRPC client for LND in C++? If so, how do you know which libraries to link with and how do you link with them?